# How to use ADB with an emulator like MEmu / Bluestacks / Nox App Player

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to use [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) with an Android emulator.
Can I fake a USB connection or how is this possible?

The emulator is *rooted*, and the *USB-Debugging* option is *On*.

I also tried via apps like adbWireless, but I get *host has failed to respond (10060)* error.

Do I always need a USB-connection for initializing?
How is it possible to connect ADB with an emulator?

Comment: Memu 7.1.3 (Android 5.1.1) is visible in Android Studio as "google G011A", you can install an application directly. After executing `adb devices` this emulator is killed (in list of devices), and Android Studio doesn't detect it until you restart the emulator.

Comment: "Nox" seems to be ambiguous. There seems to be "Nox Player", "Noxplayer", "Nox App Player", "NoxPlayer", "Nox APP Player", and "NoxPlayer for Windows". Are they all the same thing? Or are they different things? Are they all reputable? What is the canonical/most popular one?

Answer (score 41):

I'm using MEmu version 2.3 and the port used to connect it to Android Studio is 21503. Navigate to your SDK's *platformtools* directory and execute the following in *cmd*. If it fails, try to execute it again. You can also install the Samsung USB driver and try again.

```
adb connect localhost:21503
```

Comment: This worked for me on Memu version 6.3.2, don't forget to enable USB debugging on emulator developer options

Comment: I'm on 7.1.6.0 and this still works for me.
How did you knew the port number ?

Comment: I checked for open ports on my machine, tried that one and it worked.

Comment: Even though it said it got connected, I keep getting `Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` . How come?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Enable USB debugging from Settings and it will work!

Answer (score 16):

I have solved it by the following steps:

Go to the MEmu installation directory (in my case, *D:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu*):

And then delete the *adb.exe* file.
It should work fine for you.

Comment: That my friend. So clean solution.

Comment: Thanks. I restarted Memu and android studio after did it.

Answer (score 15):

For [MEmu](https://wikitia.com/wiki/MEmu_Play), [Droid4X](https://droid4x.cc/) and other [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)-based emulators, there exists a very simple way:

You need forward 5555 port to your host.

For example in Droid4X you open `\vms\droid4x\droid4x.vbox` in text editor. It is just simple xml file.

In section `<NAT>` you add line:

```
<Forwarding name="MY_PORT" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="5565" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="5555"/>
```

You can use not only 5565 port. It must be uneven and from range 5555-5585 or adb do not auto find your emulator.

Save the file and start the emulator. Now run `adb devices`, and you see `emulator-5564` in the list.

You must edit file ***only*** on fully stopped emulator or you changes will be overwritten. It means stop not just the virtual machine. You must the stop service process too. Usually it is called `VBoxSVC.exe` or `MemuSVC.exe` or another `*SVC.exe` from the folder of your emulator.

For MEmu, you need edit `\MEmu\MemuHyperv VMs\MEmu\MEmu.memu`. All others stay the same.

Comment: This way seems to be right, but it does not work on Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015, so I need an other way.

Comment: Unfortunelly changing hostport does not work. After launching emulator hostport back to previous value. That happen even if I change it right after rebooting my pc.

Comment: @dafie Because you must add new line, not edit exists.

Comment: @Enyby after adding new forwarding name with `hostport=21553` when I print `adb devices` I can only see `127.0.0.1:21503` there. I can use `adb connect 127.0.0.1:21553`, but anyway `21553` is set to offline.

Comment: @dafieYou need learn read: "You can use not only 5565 port. It must be uneven and from range 5555-5585 or adb do not auto find your emulator"

Comment: Thanks! in my case (Memu) I found the file here: C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\MemuHyperv VMs\MEmu\MEmu.memu

Answer (score 7):

In my case this command line didn't work for me:

```
adb connect localhost:21503
```

Changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` solved it:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:21503
```

Comment: I using MEmu ... For me the solution was your reverse ... adb connect 127.0.0.1:21503 not worked ...
but adb connect localhost:21503 is working .

Answer (score 3):

I am using a memu with Android 7 and after a lot of effort, I realized that on this version of Android you have to change the port to 21513 (memu version 7.2.7 / Android 7.1):

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:21513
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a step-by-step guide for the MEmu emulator.

Download and install the adbWireless app into the emulator (google "adbwireless xda"). After that, you will need to set up a network bridge, do exactly as written here, and restart your computer:

[MEmu bridge](http://www.memuplay.com/blog/index.php/2016/02/29/how-to-setup-lan/)

Then open the emulator, activate USB debugging, run *adbwireless*, and press the button. You should see the IP address, starting from "192.168". If it does not - you did something wrong.

Run the command shell with administrator privileges. Navigate with it to the folder with ADB (in my case it is "D:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmuHyperv" or add this to system Path variable). Remember the IP address from adbwireless, and then in the shell execute a command `adb connect your_ip`. In my case, it was 192.168.0.101.

The shell will notify you: `connected to 192.168.0.101:5555`. Then execute `adb devices`, so you should see the list of connected devices.
Congratulations, you are connected to MEmu using ADB.

There are more ways to set up a connection at [this post](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=717135&view=findpost&p=51687864), but it is in Russian.

Comment: Run at cmd **MEmu.exe connect 192.168.0.101:5555**. Your cmd prompt should be pointing at D:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmuHyperv

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should find the configuration file of specific emulator's VM.

E.g., MEmu's configuration vm's file is located near ~ `C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\MemuHyperv VMs\MEMU_NAME\MEMU_NAME.memu`.
Secondly, as said in the first answer, in section  you add line:

```
<Forwarding name="ADB" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="21743" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="5555"/>
```

Take the value of `hostport`, here it is `21743`.

The third step is to use ADB from MEmuHyperv `C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmuHyperv\adb.exe`. One of the possible solutions for this is to open [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), then to [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to MEmuHyperv's folder and work from there.

As MEmuHyperv is now separate project, you can download it from *[MEmuHyperv Tool](http://www.memuplay.com/blog/2016/08/08/memuhyperv-tool/)*.

Answer (score 1):

For Nox App Player, the port is 62001.

```
$ adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
connected to 127.0.0.1:62001

$ adb devices
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:62001    device

$ adb shell
root@android:/ #
```

If it does not work, please turn on "USB Debugging" first:

1. Start Nox App Player.
2. Go to "Settings" → "About tablet".
3. Tap (click) "Build number" 7 times, until it says:

   > Developer mode has been enabled.
4. Go back to the previous screen.
5. Go to "Developer options".
6. Turn on "USB debugging".
7. Restart Nox App Player.

#### Resources

- [How to connect Android Studio with Nox App Player for Android development and debug | NoxPlayer](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/)

  - The guide from the official site. Pictures for step-by-step instructions are available.
  - I found that turning on "Root", as suggested by the guide, is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**FindEmulatorPort**: Used to find the Android emulator ADB port and automatically connect, such as Tencent mobile assistant, Netease MuMu, BlueStacks, Nox App Player, and so on.

Download it from: https://gitee.com/tp7309/TTEmulatorPortFinder/repository/archive/master.zip

```
python emulator_port.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy *adb.exe* and all files you find in its folder in the Android SDK, used by your Studio. Then paste it to the MEmu folder to replace old [MEmu](https://wikitia.com/wiki/MEmu_Play) ADB. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This method works well in [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) and [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio).

Tested with NOX v7

1. Go to the nox installation folder and delete or rename both *adb.exe* and *nox_adb.exe*.
2. Go to *Environment Variables* and open *Path*. Then add your *platform-tools* folder from your SDK. For example: *D:\android-sdk\platform-tools*
3. Then go to the *platform-tools* folder and make a copy from *adb.exe* and rename it to *nox_adb.exe*. So we have both *adb.exe* and *nox_adb.exe* in *platform-tools*.

After performing these simple steps, it is better to restart the PC.