# How can I run flutter in memu emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, flutter, android-virtual-device

Can I actually run the flutter in 'outside emulator'? Something like, memu emulator or andy emulator, or something else? Well, if I run my flutter app in AVD in android studio, it will be really slow for my PC, so I want to use another emulator.

Comment: Can you tell me following things so that I can better assess your problem?
1) Which CPU processor do you have ?
2) How much RAM do you have?
3) Which emulator image are you using (ARM/x86/x86_64)?

Answer (score 1):

adb connect localhost:21503

run this command in YOURSDK\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Flutter use the adb to launch the application , if the emulator supports adb connection and able to run the android application correctly, you can connect your emulator with adb and just run the flutter project.

Memu emulator support ADB so you should be able to run the Flutter app with that.

[How to use adb with emulator like Memu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477795/how-to-use-adb-with-emulator-like-memu-bluestacks-nox-app-player)

Answer (score -1):

Follow these:

1. Find `adb.exe` in `YOURSDK\Sdk\platform-tools`.
2. Open `cmd.exe` and type `adb kill-server` then type `adb start-server`.
3. restart Memu app player.
4. check that Memu connected with `flutter devices` command.