# connect Memu Play to Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I'm programming the flutter on android studio , but for running my app i need a virtual device to connect .
Android Studio cannot find my Virtual device (Memu play) , can anyone help me about this problem.

Comment: You should try use directly the AVD from Android Studio. It s more safe than a third app.

Comment: I'll suggest the same asa Emanuel, use the official emulator from Android Studio or test some stuffs using Flutter Web with Chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594672/537347 has already answered this scenario, don't forget to enable usb debugging in Memu's emulated android os.

Answer (score 5):

First open android studio and memu play.

After sometime if the memu play instance is detected you can use it, otherwise go to memu play shortcut file location and open command prompt by typing cmd in the bar where the path is present.

After opening, type the below command :
adb connect localhost:21503

After typing the command wait for 5 seconds and the instance will be detected by Android Studio.

Note: Don't close the cmd window and memu instance until your work is finished.

If you're using BlueStacks then go to BlueStacks instance settings and then preferences and then tick the option "enable android debug bridge" and restart android studio after enabling adb.

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING SOLUTION 2023**

I had to connect the Memu emulator with the Android studio on my virtual machine of contabo. I tried different ports to connect with but ports like 21503 didn't work for me.

Type `adb devices` (get a list of emulators running with IP address and port)

Use the command `adb connect IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER` (will get ip and port from above command, this will connect your adb/emulator with Android studio and you can run the app)

[MEMU Emulator IP and port detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee76q.png)

Alternatively, you can also try different ports with this sequence.
The first gate starts at 21503
Each port after increasing the value by 10.
So for the four cases, the port values ​​would be:
21503
21513
21523
21533
And such…